# Change Documents to LibreOffice Templates (ott) not working in Ubuntu

Tags: templates

There is no difference between an .ott and an .odt document. In a template (ott), You should not be able to move or change anything like in .odt. In read only mode You can't fill out fields. 
So how do You get a real template with fillable fields ?
--- It looks like the only way to make a template with LO, is not to follow their instructions and change the odt document to pdf !